# How to display the data side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display the data side by side using the most simple code possible.

The problem is when the data is missing, the right side doesn't `float` correctly.

How to fix it?

```css
.pair {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.pair dt {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #999;
}
.pair dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="pair">
  <dt>Date</dt>
  <dd>date goes here</dd>
  <dt>Country</dt>
  <dd>USA</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt>Other</dt>
  <dd>other info goes here</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `clear: both`to `.pair dt`- this forces it to break the line

EDIT/ADDITION: I added a snippet where this is the only change.

```css
.pair {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.pair dt {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #999;
}
.pair dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="pair">
  <dt>Date</dt>
  <dd>date goes here</dd>
  <dt>Country</dt>
  <dd>USA</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt>Other</dt>
  <dd>other info goes here</dd>
</dl>
```

```css
.pair {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.pair dt {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #999;
  clear: both;
}
.pair dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="pair">
  <dt>Date</dt>
  <dd>date goes here</dd>
  <dt>Country</dt>
  <dd>USA</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt>Other</dt>
  <dd>other info goes here</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: OK this works! and its the most simple solution. I just needed to add overflow:auto to the DL tag

Comment: @Marco simpler than using `dd:empty{clear:left}` ? You even said you add to add an `overflow` to this solution. Not so simple after all

Comment: @dippas: its one more selector i need to write in the css. I prefer using the ones that already exist. I do appreciate your effort

Comment: @dippas hey, you got more votes than I got - so why do you complain? ;-)

Comment: Not complaining at all my friend ;) just trying to tell OP that's not the most simple solution as OP stated. ;) I really don't care for the upvotes, just trying to help as much as I know/can here :) @Johannes

Answer (score 3):

you need to add `dd:empty {clear:left}`

and  you may want a `float:left` in `.pair` (optional)

```css
.pair {
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: left
}
.pair dt {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #999;

}
.pair dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 100px;
}
.pair dd:empty {
  clear: left
}
```

```html
<dl class="pair">
  <dt>Date</dt>
  <dd>date goes here</dd>
  <dt>Country</dt>
  <dd>USA</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd>00</dd>
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd>xxxx</dd>
  <dt>Other</dt>
  <dd>other info goes here</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="pair">
  <dt>Date</dt>
  <dd>date goes here</dd>
  <dt>Country</dt>
  <dd>USA</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt>Name</dt>
  <dd></dd>
  <dt>Other</dt>
  <dd>other info goes here</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear. i don't want the dt list to be side by side, i want the data inside the dt list to be side by side. I've changed my post so it's clearer.

Comment: @Marco see updated answer. I updated while you were commented